# How to avoid iPhone automatically adding Map URL to SMS message?

Tags: ios, sms

My App allows users to share items from the App with their friends through SMS messages, which contains a deeplink that brings the recipient to that item in the App.  I have noticed a few occasions where an extra link is automatically added to the SMS message that when pressed opens up the Map App on the phone and tries to go to an address.  This is confusing to the user since the item being shown is a baseball card and the first link goes to an address instead of the item as expected.  An example text that turns into a url is:

> 1933 Goudey #149 Babe Ruth PSA 4

[image]

Does anyone know how to turn off this functionality?  I couldn't find any references to it.

Comment: That's a "feature" of the Messages app. There is nothing your app can do other than perhaps format the text so there is no way it can be interpreted as an address.

Comment: @rmaddy Ouch, that is tough.  Thanks for the info, if you want to post it as an answer I will accept it tomorrow if no one comes up with a solution.